# symfony2 Unknown Entity namespace alias in formtype class

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two connection of database in config.yml:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        default:
            host:     %database_host%
            port:     %database_port%
            dbname:   %database_name%
            user:     %database_user%
            password: %database_password%
            driver:   %database_driver%
            charset:  UTF8
        spoop:
            host:     %database_host%
            port:     %database_port%
            dbname:   %spoop_database_name%
            user:     %spoop_database_user%
            password: %spoop_database_password%              
            driver:   %database_driver%
            charset:  UTF8

orm:
    default_entity_manager:   default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection:       default
            #metadata_cache_driver: apc
            #query_cache_driver: apc
            #result_cache_driver: apc
            mappings:
                AcmeUserBundle: ~
                AcmeBannieresBundle: ~
                FOSUserBundle: ~
                #SpoopAdminBundle: ~
        spoop:
            connection:       spoop
            #metadata_cache_driver: apc
            #query_cache_driver: apc
            #result_cache_driver: apc
            mappings:
                AcmeModerationBundle: ~

    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
```

so in my acmeModerationBundle, i use the spoop connection. I have a formtype like this in Acme\ModerationBundle\Form:

```
    class ModerationAnnonceForm extends AbstractType{
        public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
            ->add('descAnnonce')
            ->add('idRubrique','entity',array(
                    'class' => 'AcmeModerationBundle:TRubrique',
                    'expanded'=>true,
                    'multiple' =>false,
            ));
        }
        public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
        {
            return array(
                'data_class' => 'Acme\ModerationBundle\Entity\TAnnonces',
            );
        }
        public function getName()
        {
            return 'acme_moderationbundle_annonceform';
        }
    }
```

the AcmeModerationBundle:TRubrique is defined in the proper place : Acme/Moderationbundle/Entity/TRubrique. When i trying to generate this form, i always get this:
Unknown Entity namespace alias 'AcmeModerationBundle'. I take a look in the log,

```
    at ORMException ::unknownEntityNamespace ('AcmeModerationBundle')
    in D:\workspace\symfony_bannieres\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Configuration.php at line 174  -+
    at Configuration ->getEntityNamespace ('AcmeModerationBundle')
    in D:\workspace\symfony_bannieres\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php at line 156  -+
    at ClassMetadataFactory ->getMetadataFor ('AcmeModerationBundle:TRubrique')
    in D:\workspace\symfony_bannieres\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php at line 257  -+
    at EntityManager ->getClassMetadata ('AcmeModerationBundle:TRubrique')
    in D:\workspace\symfony_bannieres\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\EntityChoiceList.php at line 113  -+
    at EntityChoiceList ->__construct (object(EntityManager), 'AcmeModerationBundle:TRubrique', null, null, null)
    in D:\workspace\symfony_bannieres\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType.php at line 62  -+

    at EntityType ->getDefaultOptions (array('class' => 'AcmeModerationBundle:TRubrique', 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => false, 'data' => null))
    in D:\workspace\symfony_bannieres\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory.php at line 234  -
```

i suppose it use the default entity manager, i check the php app/console container:debug

```
    doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager           container Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
    doctrine.orm.entity_manager                   n/a       alias for doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
    doctrine.orm.spoop_entity_manager             container Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
```

Anyone can tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) accepts an `em` option which lets you specify the entity manager

```
<?php

class ModerationAnnonceForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('descAnnonce')
        ->add('idRubrique','entity',array(
                'class' => 'AcmeModerationBundle:TRubrique',
                'em' => 'spoop' // Add this
                'expanded'=>true,
                'multiple' =>false,
        ));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this when tried to use bandle name without core folder name. It was in config/security.yml

Folder structure in my case is the next src/Dp/UserBundle/....

I changed this 
`providers:

```
    main:
        entity: { class: UserBundle:User, property: username }`
```

to this 
`providers:

```
    main:
        entity: { class: DpUserBundle:User, property: username }`
```

So copy name of unknown Entity name (UserBundle my case )and search each entries in project, check - they have to be with folder prefix (Dp in my case)